# Why makefile not compiling a new library when I delete manually an object file?

Tags: makefile

I have a special use case without to understand if it is right, or I wrote a wrong makefile. (I think that is completely ok)

I have the following demo make file to build a hex file for my AVR:

```
__CFILES := a.c b.c d.c
__OBJS := $(__CFILES:.c=.obj)
__LIB := path/to/demo/lib.a
# Dependency include 
-include $(__CFILES:.c=.d)
#################### Main Target ####################
all: $(__TARGET_HEX)
# Build hex file
$(__TARGET_HEX): $(__LIB)
     @echo *******************************************************************************
     @echo Link Libraries and generate HEX file.
     @echo *******************************************************************************
     $(DEMO COMMAND FOR LINKING ETC)

$(__LIB): $(__OBJS)
     @echo *******************************************************************************
     @echo Linking all objects and generate __LIB library.
     @echo *******************************************************************************
     $(COMMAND TO MAKE A LIBRARY FROM OBJs)

$(__OBJS):
    @echo Compiling $(@:.obj=.c)
    $(COMMAND TO COMPILE)
```

The use case is the following, when I remove an object file manually from my local disk then the process makes nothing, only generate a HEX file from the old library.

If I delete all the objects makes also the same process.

Now I change the time stamp of a C file and i start the build process again, then makes a compiling for all objects, which are deleted and generates a new library.

I dont know if is it ok but seems to generate a new lib only when a source file is changed and making nothing if a object file is deleted.

Can someone tell me if I made something wrong in syntax? I think that is not wrong and make file is so smart that can recognize when to build a new library, but i need your help to understand deeper what is going on.

Comment: Is this your complete makefile? Because I don't see how what you are saying is happening matches with the contents here. Can you show (via copy and paste) the series of commands you run for each situation and what exactly make does as a result?

Comment: @EtanReisner The original make file is 300 lines and includes some other makefiles, what do you mean "the series of commands " ?

Comment: I mean the original `make` you run, then the `touch`/`rm`/etc. you run to change things and then `make` again. And pastebin the makefile(s) if you don't want to include them here. The output from `make -d` might also be useful in the cases where make rebuilds too much or not enough (though that will also be a *large* amount of lines).

Comment: One problem is nothing in this makefile actually depends on the `.c` files. @EtanReisner is right, there has to be more going on here.  I recommend you run with the `--trace` flag and see what make is really doing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, i want to explain that if someone use as Target a file, like a lib, then the make file looks if the target files is newer as the objects and all the C files, if is it newer then do nothing.

If the target is a name, like `lib` then builds always a new library. Following an example!

```
__CFILES := a.c b.c d.c
__OBJS := $(__CFILES:.c=.obj)
__LIB := path/to/demo/lib.a
# Dependency include 
-include $(__CFILES:.c=.d)
#################### Main Target ####################
all: $(__TARGET_HEX)
# Build hex file
$(__TARGET_HEX): lib
    @echo     *******************************************************************************
     @echo Link Libraries and generate HEX file.
     @echo     *******************************************************************************
     $(DEMO COMMAND FOR LINKING ETC)

lib: $(__OBJS)
     @echo     *******************************************************************************
     @echo Linking all objects and generate __LIB library.
     @echo     *******************************************************************************
     $(COMMAND TO MAKE A LIBRARY FROM OBJs)

$(__OBJS):
    @echo Compiling $(@:.obj=.c)
    $(COMMAND TO COMPILE)
```